# Java Arrays after destroying still in RAM

Tags: java, load, ram, destroy

Hello I working on terraria clone. I have dynamic chunks loading system (If chunk is visible load him) but I have problem when I want to destory chunk when is not visible. My destroying is something like this:

```
public void destroy() {
    blocks = null;
    background_blocks = null;
    light_map = null;
}
```

But that dont want to work this is still in RAM. Can someone explain why ? (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: How do you know that it's still in RAM? In any case there is no reason to worry about it. The memory will be cleaned up when necessary. Also you may be able to just keep the entire map in memory all the time. In terraria even a large map has only 20 million blocks and since you only need 1 or 2 bytes per block, you can store everything in just 20 to 40 MB of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't understand what you are asking. I guess you might want to know:

Why when you set the variable null, the array is still in RAM?

Java has a *GC* system, which collects variables which are not used and delete them from ram. But always remember that GC will not be running after a object becomes garbage. When to run GC depends on the moods of system. So even if you set it null, it will not be cleared from ram until some times later.

If this is not you want, tell me.

Comment: @NoName You're welcome. Would you mind marking me as the best answer using the √ symbol?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot about it sorry.